# Angular 4 Execute Function when html fully loaded

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a problem with asynchronous HTTP calls in Angular 4 using typescript/components... I create an array of objects, and in the HTML I have checkboxes next to the objects. Now I want certain objects to be checked, by executing a function in angular. However when I do

```
 (document.getElementById(id) as HTMLInputElement).checked = true;
```

In my component.ts.
It can't find the element however when I do the same code in a function that executes when you push a button it works. So the problem is that the HTML is not fully loaded when I execute the function. How can I make sure the HTML is fully loaded?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to manipulate the DOM that way in Angular. Instead set the desired state as a property on your component and use one-way or two way binding as appropriate to set the checked attribute in the HTML template.

Comment: okay, but if i do  <input type="checkbox" id="{{drawing.name}}"  checked="{{drawing.flag}}"/> all elements are checked but not all flags are true

Comment: that's why you should use [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) instead of binding to `checked` attribute. You should read the [forms guide](https://angular.io/guide/forms)...

Comment: I gave my drawing a flag attribute and so I could do [checked]="drawing.flag" in my input element

Answer (score 1):

Yeah You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM.

- Tag your HTML element in the html using hash.

  `<input ... #inputname />`
- Retrieved in the ts controller component.

  `@ViewChild('inputname') theinput;`
- Check after view init. *ngAfterViewInit* if it is checked

  `ngAfterViewInit() {
      ...
      (this.form as HTMLInputElement).checked
      ...
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as the last option since I wouldn't recommend direct DOM manipulation in Angular. But if you are still facing the issue, use can use my solution as a work around.

In **constructor** ,

```
let interval = setInterval(() => {
        let flag = self.checkFunction();
        if (flag)
            clearInterval(interval);
    }, 100)
```

Now create the function

```
checkFunction() {
    if(document.getElementById(id)){
         (document.getElementById(id) as HTMLInputElement).checked = true;
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```